# Pass ColdFusion variables to .php file

Tags: php, variables, coldfusion

I am trying to pass a ColdFusion variable into a .PHP file. The essential gist of what I am trying to do is call on a CF variable in a .php API file. I did not know if this was even possible or not but I followed the flow of this thread: [Pass a form field from a Coldfusion page to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795479/pass-a-form-field-from-a-coldfusion-page-to-php)

While trying to use the API it did not recognize the variable and I am pretty sure I am calling on it wrong. Any help is appreciated as always!

ColdFusion Form:

```
<cfform action="/stripped.php" method="post">
        
    <label for="Search" style="color: #fff !Important;"> Variable Form PHP:</label>
        
    <cfinput type="text" name="Variable" required="Yes" message="Please enter a Variable." class=" form-control" >         
    <input style="margin-top:20px;" type="submit" value="Send Variable" class="btn red-btn">
</cfform>
```

.PHP file Params:

```
$params = ["contactPhone" => '#form.Variable#', "mode" => "AUTO", "subject" => "Test 0.0", "text" => "TEST TEXT IGNORE!"];
```

Comment: What would that `$params` command look like if the form was on a php page?

Comment: Are you asking how I would create the CF form in php? I do not know PHP so I really don't know what it would look like. I mainly work in CF, but I have been tasked to use a php API from a third party.

Comment: From ColdFusion or any other source, if there's a form that submits regular _post_ data to a PHP script, then that data will be available in PHP in the `$_POST` variable, in an array, e.g. `$_POST['Variable']` for your `Variable` input field.

Comment: Thank you Markus! This was able to get me where I needed. I had played with $_POST earlier but did not have my formatting right. I had tried something like $POST['#form.Variable'].